# Count All Character Occurrences in a String C#

Tags: c#, string, count, character

What is the best way to dynamically count each character occurrence in C#?

given

```
string sample = "Foe Doe";
```

it should output something like

```
f = 1
o = 2
e = 2
d = 1
```

counting a single character would be easy but in my exam this was a bit tricky, I could only imagine a solution to get all unique characters -> then store it in a collection(preferably an array) then a nested for loop for the array and the string.

Is there a better solution than this?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<char, int>` to keep track of the counts for each character.

Comment: *Each character* means *each letter*?

Comment: Define "best": Fastest? Easiest to understand? Easiest to code? "Cleverest"?

Comment: Also do you need to take case into account?  Your example seems to indicate that you want a case insensitive approach.

Comment: @juharr Gosh why didn't I think of that!

Comment: @MatthewWatson sorry I by that I mean easiest to understand

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it is :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use LINQ

```
sample.GroupBy(c => c).Select(c => new { Char = c.Key, Count = c.Count()});
```

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more, this takes advantage of the fact that `string` is a collection of `char`s, so `GroupBy` will happily iterate over it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq for that:

```
sample.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => $"{x.Key} = {x.Count()}").
```

And tweaking you can remove empty characters, make case insensitive, etc..

```
str.ToLower().GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Key != ' ').Select(x => $"{x.Key} = {x.Count()}")
```

And so on..

Comment: @KonstantinErshov beat me to it :p

Comment: Instead of creating a new `string` by invoking `.ToLower`, you could just `Char.ToLower` as a `GroupBy` expression and utilize `Char.IsWhiteSpace` to check for whitespaces, not only regular spaces.

Comment: Nice, i'm not used to the string/char validation/transformation native functions. I'll add those to my daily basis!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`Lookup<k,e>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx) which is similar to a dictionary:

```
var charLookup = sample.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToLookup(c => c); // IsLetterOrDigit to exclude the space

foreach (var c in charLookup)
    Console.WriteLine("Char:{0} Count:{1}", c.Key, charLookup[c.Key].Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string inputstring = "Hello World";
        var count = 0;

        var charGroups = (from s in inputstring
                          group s by s into g
                          select new
                          {
                              c = g.Key,
                              count = g.Count(),
                          }).OrderBy(c => c.count);
        foreach (var x in charGroups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.c + ": " + x.count);
            count = x.count;
        }

        Console.Read();     

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, you can use the Linq .Where() and .GroupBy() extensions to count the letters and eliminate the whitespace.

```
string sample = "Foe Doe";

var letterCounter = sample.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit)
                          .GroupBy(char.ToLower)
                          .Select(counter => new { Letter = counter.Key, Counter = counter.Count() });

foreach (var counter in letterCounter)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", counter.Letter, counter.Counter));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
          string str;
          int i, cnt;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence");
        str = Console.ReadLine();
        char ch;
        for (ch = (char)65; ch <= 90; ch++)
        {
            cnt = 0;
            for ( i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {

                if (ch == str[i] || (ch + 32) == str[i])
                {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            if (cnt > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ch + "=" + cnt);
            }
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
      string str = "Orasscleee";
        Dictionary<char,int> c=new Dictionary<char, int>();
        foreach (var cc in str)
        {
            char c1 = char.ToUpper(cc);
            try
            {
                c.Add(c1,1);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                c[c1] = c[c1] + 1;
            }
        }
        foreach (var c1 in c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{c1.Key}:{c1.Value}");

        }
```

Comment: What part you didn't get?

Answer (score -1):

```
        string new_string= String.Concat(s.OrderBy(c => c)); //for sorting string
        for (int i = 0; i < new_string.Length; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < new_string.Length; j++)
            {

                if (new_string[i] == new_string[j])
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (count == 0)
                    { count = 1; }
                    break;
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("count for "+new_string[i]+"is: "+count);
            new_string=new_string.Remove(0, count);
            i = 0;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Hello welcome to SO, can you briefly explain how your answer is suppose to help OP's question?