# Counting duplicate chars in a C# string

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and trying to work out how to count the number of duplicates in a string. Example input and output would be:

```
"indivisibility" -> 1 # 'i' occurs six times
"Indivisibilities" -> 2 # 'i' occurs seven times and 's' occurs twice
"aA11" -> 2 # 'a' and '1'
"ABBA" -> 2 # 'A' and 'B' each occur twice
```

My code so far is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;

public class Kata
{
  public static int DuplicateCount(string str)
  {
    Stack checkedChars = new Stack();
    Stack dupChars = new Stack(); 

    str = str.ToLower();

    for (int i=1; i < str.Length; i++) {
      var alreadyCounted = checkedChars.Contains(str[i]) && dupChars.Contains(str[i]);

      if (!checkedChars.Contains(str[i])) {
         checkedChars.Push(str[i]);
      } else if (checkedChars.Contains(str[i])) {
         dupChars.Push(str[i]);
      } else if (alreadyCounted) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return dupChars.Count;
  }
}
```

My approach is to loop through each character in the string. If it hasn't been seen before, to add it to a 'checkedChars' Stack (to keep track of it). If it's already been counted, add it to a 'dupChars' Stack. However, this is failing the tests. E.g:

`aabbcde` is the string, and the test fails with: `Expected: 2 But Was: 1`

Also when I console out errors, it appears that the checkedChars Stack is empty.

Can anyone spot where I have gone wrong please?

Comment: A string is a char [], `GroupBy` char and select the one that have more than one occurrence.

Comment: Why are you using a `Stack`? I'd use a `Dictionary<char, int>` to keep count.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count All Character Occurrences in a String C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472429/count-all-character-occurrences-in-a-string-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get an array of repeated characters from a string using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245369/how-do-i-get-an-array-of-repeated-characters-from-a-string-using-linq)

Comment: You will need 6 stacks for `indivisibility`

Comment: Start counting from 0 when looping over the characters in the string.

Comment: Weird question I and i count as the same.. Do we handle Turk too? If that the for each char store the lower culture invariant in a dictionary like  `dictionary.TryGetValue(lowerChar, out int count);
        dictionary[lowerChar] = count + 1;` and filter it by value >1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest you use LINQ instead.  It's a more suitable tool for the problem, and it results in much cleaner code:

```
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
          var word = "indivisibility";
          Console.WriteLine($"{word} has {CountDuplicates(word)} duplicates.");
          word = "Indivisibilities";
          Console.WriteLine($"{word} has {CountDuplicates(word)} duplicates.");
          word = "aA11";
          Console.WriteLine($"{word} has {CountDuplicates(word)} duplicates.");
          word = "ABBA";
          Console.WriteLine($"{word} has {CountDuplicates(word)} duplicates.");

          Console.ReadLine();
     }
     public static int CountDuplicates(string str) =>
            (from c in str.ToLower()
             group c by c
             into grp
             where grp.Count() > 1
             select grp.Key).Count();
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
indivisibility has 1 duplicates.
Indivisibilities has 2 duplicates.
aA11 has 2 duplicates.
ABBA has 2 duplicates.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the loop at `int i = 0`, because indexing start at 0 and not 1. So to get the first character you'll need to call `str[0]`.

You can also remove the `break` as your code will never hit it, since the first 2 conditions are exactly the opposite of each other. Instead check first if `alreadyCounted` is true and use `continue` (not `break` as it will exit the loop entirely!) to skip to the next iteration, to avoid counting the same characters more than once.

Answer (score 0):

you can use LINQ for this -

```
    var str = "aabbcde";
    var count = str.ToLower().GroupBy(x => x).Select(y => y).Where(z=>z.Count()>1).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use MoreLinq.CountBy:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MoreLinq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static int CountDuplicateCharacters(string s)
        {
            return s?.CountBy(c => c).Where(kvp => kvp.Value > 1).Count() ?? 0;
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var s in new string[] { "indivisibility", "Indivisibilities", "aA11", "ABBA" })
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s + ": " + CountDuplicateCharacters(s));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In case you do not want to differentiate between lower and upper case you need to supply an EqualityComparer as a second argument to CountBy.